# What should I do if Visual Studio has a restriction on creating files with a long name or a long path to these files?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, avaloniaui

When I make a project, I make a lot of folders and subfolders, separating files by topic. But it happens that the file paths are too long and Visual Studio gives an error. How can I fix it?

a little project to make applications with all sorts of tests for school, right away I say that I am not American and now I am in Russia, the project is done on AvaloniaUI

here's a link to GutHub: https://github.com/Zakarayaev/QuizApplication

file creation error: The complete path to 'SelectltemOfNounTestViewModel.cs•
exceeds the maximum number of characters permitted by the
file system.

Comment: It's probably your operating system rather than visual studio that's imposing the maximum path length - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

Comment: I already tried that, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Please post some code (minimum reproducable example) to demonstrate your issue, and the details for any exception raised.

Comment: The short answer is to make your paths shorter. An easy way to do this is to move the repo directory as close to the root of a drive as possible, like `c:\dev\QuizApplication` The problem is not usually the name of any individual file but the full length of the path which has a maximum of 260 characters.

Comment: What if I create more internal folders and then this error occurs again?

Comment: If you have your code under your user folder like Vs does by default then that could be your problem. I once worked somewhere they included the apostrophe I have in my surname in my user name. Their standard was to work with code in our user folders. That apostrophe caused a too long path error. Maybe other characters cause the same issue.